# How do I update Dictionary values (object) irrespective of key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has more than 2000+ elements. I am trying to update an element in the value based on a condition. How do I do that in a simple statement instead of looping through?

```
Dictionary<int, MyObj> testDictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyObj>();
testDictionary.Add(1,new MyObj() {Name = "John",Code = "JN",Id = null});
testDictionary.Add(2,new MyObj() {Name = "John",Code = "JN",Id = null});
testDictionary.Add(3,new MyObj() {Name = "Champ",Code = "CP",Id = null});
testDictionary.Add(4,new MyObj() {Name = "SMITH",Code = "SH",Id = null});
testDictionary.Add(5,new MyObj() {Name = "SMITH",Code = "SH",Id = null});


Dictionary<int, MyObj>

public class MyObj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

How do I update all of Dictionary values (MyObj)

```
where Code = JN and Name = John with 100
where Code = SH and Name = SMITH with 989
```

I can get matched list using below statement but do I ressign to dictionary?

```
var enList = testDictionary.Values.Where(d => d.Name == "John" && d.Code == "JN");
```

Comment: Yes you can query items like you wrote above and then in foreach loop make updates

Comment: @Serghei foreach and set the value, how to assign back to dictionary?

Comment: Look they already in Dictionary you don't need to reassign them becasuse in dictionary you store only references to you objects of class MyObj. just update the values let say Name and you will see it. when you make a select by key from dictionary that Value already updated

Comment: how do you want to update items give an example?

Comment: I've posted answer take a look if I understand you correctly

Comment: It's not clear what you need help with. What's your _question_? As some have pointed out, since `MyObj` is a class, it's possible to modify the object directly without changing the dictionary itself, and that's easy enough to do. But, is that really what you want to do? Do you actually have some requirement that the dictionary needs to be updated with a new object instance? And in any case, what _specifically_ are you having trouble with? What have you tried? Why didn't that work? Your question should include a [mcve] along with a detailed explanation, both of which help answer those questions

Answer (score 1):

Try the code bellow, this change the value of name to test attribute in any item where the value of `Name` is "SMITH".

```
testDictionary.Where(y => y.Value.Name == "SMITH")
              .Select(r => r.Value)
              .ToList<MyObj>()
              .ForEach(k => k.Name = "test");
```

This line does not return result, the value is changed directly in the `textDictionary` instance.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example - you don't need to reassign values in the Dictionary, they are stored as references.

```
var enList = testDictionary.Values.Where(d => d.Name == "John" && d.Code == "JN").ToList();

foreach (var item in enList)
{
    item.Name = "Updated Name";

}

Console.WriteLine(testDictionary[1].Name);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know.